# How to check a condition before the render of the component happen?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to redirect the user to the /dashboard page if the user is already signed in. However the home page (/) will always get rendered first and then useEffect kicks in, then the route would be redirected to /dashboard.

If you go to https://vercel.com, and if you are signed in then you don’t pause at the homepage route first and then get redirected to https://vercel.com/dashboard.

This is how I am approaching it right now (BTW I am using nextjs). I am using useLayoutEffect to check if the currentUser(comes from my useContext hook) is available, and if it is then push it to /dashboard:

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Home = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser && currentUser.email) {
      router.push('/dashboard');
    }
  }, [currentUser]);

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="sm" className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container className={classes.gridContainer}>
        <Link href="/login">
          <Button>
            Login
          </Button>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/signup">
          <Button>
            Sign up
          </Button>
        </Link>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Can't you just put the redirect without using an effect ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user has to go somewhere essentially. I suppose the currentUser is fetched in the context. While this request takes place you could expose a loading state from the context as well, and show an indication that you are fetching data.
It has no value for the user to see the /home screen when he is possibly redirected to /dashboard after 1sec, so show a spinner or something better until it is clear where the user has to go.

I would not do it with useLayoutEffect. This hook is reserved for changes regarding the DOM or rendering, not networking workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think if you add a flag to delay render until you check if the user logged in?
Also, I believe you can just use `useEffect` here.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Home = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser && currentUser.email) {
      router.push('/dashboard');
    } else {
       setChecked(true)
    }
  }, [currentUser]);

  if (!checked) return null;

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="sm" className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container className={classes.gridContainer}>
        <Link href="/login">
          <Button>
            Login
          </Button>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/signup">
          <Button>
            Sign up
          </Button>
        </Link>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Home;
```